# How should my data be formatted for 1v1 match prediction?

Tags: predictive-models, modeling, data-transformation, dataset

I want to build a model that predicts 1v1 tennis match outcomes. What is the best way to layout my data? Essentially is it better to have 1 row per match or create rows/observations from each player's perspective (2 rows per match)?

Method 1:

```
player| opponent | player_feature | opponent_feature | result
-------------------------------------------------------------
Alice |  Bob     |   10           |  20              | W
```

Method 2:

```
player| opponent | player_feature | opponent_feature | result
-------------------------------------------------------------
Alice |  Bob     |   10           |  20              | W
Bob   |  Alice   |  20            |  10              | L
```

Answer (score 0):

In Method 2, the rows are essentially duplicates of each other, so Method 1 is a better choice.

The only occasion that Method 2 would be better is if there was some underlying difference between being a "player" and being an "opponent". Maybe it correlates with playing Home or Away, or which end of the court they're playing. Even then, it would be better to include that information as an additional feature.